# What language is the Ubuntu Software Center written in?

Tags: software-center, gui, programming

Just been wondering, since elementary AppCenter is written with Vala and Gtk+3.

Also, what GUI wrapper does it use?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. Go to http://packages.ubuntu.com/
2. Search for "*software center*" and click on the one with exact name. It should be `software-center`

   > **Package software-center**
   >
   > - [trusty (14.04LTS)](http://packages.ubuntu.com/trusty/software-center) (gnome): Utility for browsing, installing, and removing software
   >
   >   13.10-0ubuntu4: all
3. On the right side, look for *External Resources* ([Home Page](https://launchpad.net/software-center)[launchpad.net])
4. In *Project information*, [Browse the code](http://bazaar.launchpad.net/~ubuntuone-control-tower/software-center/trunk/files)
5. In root folder, it is clear that it is a Python project.

   ```
   setup.cfg
   setup.py
   ```

   No Makefile, Autotools, cmake...
6. `src` not there, looking for an interesting folder name. `softwarecenter` seems so, in python folder with `__init.py__` could be used as module.
7. Looking inside then `ui` folder, it has two GUI interfaces *gtk3* & *qml*
8. For wrappers used, see `app.py` in each folder

   **gtk3**

   ```
   from gi.repository import GObject
   from gi.repository import GLib
   from gi.repository import Gtk
   ```

   **qml**

   ```
   from PyQt4 import QtDeclarative
   from PyQt4.QtCore import QUrl
   from PyQt4.QtGui import QApplication, QIcon
   from PyQt4.QtDeclarative import QDeclarativeView
   ```

**Note:**

An alternative way, if you don't want to browse the web. You can activate source code repository then download its source using:

```
apt-get source software-center
```

(Notice *NO `sudo`*)

Answer (score 1):

USC is written in Python, PyGTK/PyGObject based on the toolkit GTK+ and the GNOME application, gnome-app-install.